# event not fired for the second time to load data from a database

Tags: c#, events

I defined an Event to load data from a database through a Method. But the second time, new data could not be loaded in a treeview, it didn't work! nothing loaded!

```
public custom_unit_form()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // add
    _load_data_ms += new EventHandler(load_data_db_ms);
}

private void load_data_db_ms()
{
   // data loaded from database in treeview
}
```

When a new data is added to the database, the event is fired, but only the first time works and second time nothing happens.

```
private void new_data()
{
   // fire the event
   _load_data_ms.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: How is new_data called?

Comment: @CodingYoshi
it's a part of viewmodel code
protected virtual void OnViewModelChanged_2(object sender, 
       PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var vm = sender as ViewModel;
            if (vm == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // chose
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
               ......... codes to do
                 _load_data_ms.Invoke();
            }
      }

Comment: That code does not call new_data

Comment: In the second form (when click on add button, new item is added to a database), afterthat, in the first form, (treeview loads data by connecting to the database to get all data again by EVENT)
but the second time, event cann't be fired!

Comment: You don't get what I mean. The event is fired when new_data is called, so if new_data is not called again then the event will not fire.

Comment: No, When the event -> is invoked, then the method -> load data from the database. 
I put <event that is called [_load_data_ms.Invoke();] 
inside the 
protected virtual void OnViewModelChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) code

Comment: Could you show where you use `new_data()` ? This is doesn't provide enough information to figure out what is wrong.